# How to fetch data from API using id in reactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, fetch-api

How do I pass an ID from one API to another, and fetch the require data?

This is my code:

```js
handleClick(e){
    fetch("http://api.com/product_sub_categories?category_id")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(
      (result) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          product_sub_categories: result.product_sub_categories
        });
      },
      (error) => {
        this.setState({
          isLoaded: true,
          error
        });
      }
    )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do using back tick.

```
handleClick(e){
  fetch(`${BASE_PATH}/product_sub_categories?category_id=${e.target.value}`)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(
    (result) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        product_sub_categories: result.product_sub_categories
      });
    },
    (error) => {
      this.setState({
        isLoaded: true,
        error
      });
    }
  )
}
```